# How can I translate keyword prototype in AS3 to Haxe?

Tags: actionscript-3, ecmascript-6, haxe

I have the below AS3 code, and I want to translate it to Haxe. But I don't know how to deal with the keyword `prototype`. Who can help me? Thanks.

```
    var style = new CSSStyleDeclaration(); 
    style.defaultFactory = function():void
    {
       this.disabledOverlayAlpha = 0;
       this.borderStyle = "controlBar";
       this.paddingTop = 10;
       this.verticalAlign = "middle";
       this.paddingLeft = 10;
       this.paddingBottom = 10;
       this.paddingRight = 10;
    };
    if(chain == null) chain = {};
    style.defaultFactory.prototype = chain;
    chain = new style.defaultFactory();
    
    style.defaultFactory = function():void
    {
       this.fontWeight = "bold";
    };

    style.defaultFactory.prototype = chain;
    chain = new style.defaultFactory();

    style.defaultFactory = function():void
    {
           this.backgroundSize = "100%";
           this.paddingTop = 24;
           this.backgroundColor = 8821927;
           this.backgroundImage = ApplicationBackground;
           this.horizontalAlign = "center";
           this.backgroundGradientAlphas = [1,1];
           this.paddingLeft = 24;
           this.paddingBottom = 24;
           this.paddingRight = 24;
      };

     style.defaultFactory.prototype = chain;
     chain = new style.defaultFactory();
```

Comment: The **prototype** keyword is a very hack-y way to use inheritance (if it is at all **AS3**, more like **AS1/2**): https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#prototype I suggest you (instead of porting this to **HAXE** directly) to figure what exactly this code does and port a *meaningful* version of it.

Comment: The other issue, defaultFactory is a type of Function, Haxe doesn't support new defaultFactory()

Comment: Only more the reason to understand what this piece is supposed to do and re-write it anew in a legit **HAXE** way, rather than trying to port it in a carbon copy way.

Comment: @PeterZhou _"Haxe doesn't support new defaultFactory()"_ maybe create a new Class instead of Function? Keyword `prototype` is a shortcut to make an **inline** function (add some new function inside another existing function). Regardless if defaultFactory is a Function or Class, either way you will access the inline/prototype chain function as `defaultFactory.chain();` but only Class can have `new`. Why that is needed in the shown code is beyond me... `chain = new defaultFactory();` means you want a function called chain to contain an inline function called chain also? Like `chain.chain();`???

Comment: Hi everyone, I use AS3HX tool to translate AS3 code to HAXE. However, there are endless errors in HAXE code. AS3HX doesn't know how to translate the above code to HAXE, it only directly copies the code to HAXE. There is not chain() method, chain is an object, it equals to new defaultFactory(), and is linked to another defaultFactory. Who have the experience of using AS3HX?

Comment: My issue is how to translate these code to haxe: style = new CSSStyleDeclaration();style.defaultFactory = function():void
            {
               this.disabledOverlayAlpha = 0;
               this.borderStyle = "controlBar";
               this.paddingTop = 10;
               this.verticalAlign = "middle";
               this.paddingLeft = 10;
               this.paddingBottom = 10;
               this.paddingRight = 10;
            };  style.defaultFactory.prototype = chain;
            chain = new style.defaultFactory();

Comment: I advise you to **edit** your question and update it with the full and nicely formatted version of the scripts, because in the comment form, as you probably see, it is an unreadable mess.

Comment: Okay, I updated the code to nicely format. please see the above code in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I poked this a bit, and now I kind of figured out, what that piece of code does. This knowledge won't help you to port your code to **HAXE**, but it **will** help you understand what it is about and to compose a decent **HAXE**-style alternative.

**First**, the part about instantiating, functions and working with prototypes. As it turned out, if you invoke the **new** operator on an unbound function (does not work on class methods):

1. The new empty class-less generic **Object** is created.
2. Its reference is passed to the said function as **this**.
3. The function can add and modify the object's fields and methods.
4. Ultimately, the reference to that **Object** is returned.

Then, it works (as I mentioned in my comments above) very much the way classes worked back then in **AS1** and **Flash 6**.

If that function has a **prototype** and it is too a generic **Object**, then it is added to the newly created one as a... how to put it... a *bottom* layer **Object** which adds its fields to the *top* layer **Object**.

I understand that it sounds difficult, so there's an explanatory example that somehow sheds some light on it all:

```
public class Proton extends Sprite
{
    
    public function Proton() 
    {
        super();
        
        var P:Function;
        
        // Empty.
        P = new Function;
        create("First:", P);
        
        // Empty with prototype.
        P.prototype = {c:3, d:4};
        create("Second:", P);
        
        // Non-empty.
        P = function():void
        {
            this.a = 1;
            this.b = 2;
        };
        create("Third:", P);
        
        // Non-empty with prototype.
        P.prototype = {a:5, f:6};
        create("Fourth:", P);
    }
    
    // Instantiates the F and outputs the result.
    private function create(prefix:String, F:Function):void
    {
        var A:Object = new F;
        
        trace(prefix + "\nJSON:" + JSON.stringify(A) + "\nREAL:" + explore(A) + "\n");
    }
    
    // Same as JSON.stringify, but also looks into the prototype.
    private function explore(O:Object):String
    {
        var result:Array = new Array;
        
        for (var akey:String in O)
        {
            result.push('"' + akey + '":' + O[akey]);
        }
        
        return "{" + result.join(",") + "}";
    }
}
```

So, the output is:

```
First:
JSON:{}
REAL:{}

Second:
JSON:{}
REAL:{"d":4,"c":3}

Third:
JSON:{"b":2,"a":1}
REAL:{"b":2,"a":1}

Fourth:
JSON:{"b":2,"a":1}
REAL:{"b":2,"a":1,"f":6,"a":1}
```

As you can see, **JSON.stringify** exports only the *top* layer object, while direct **for** iteration goes through all the layers, *top* to *bottom*, and even processes the duplicate keys (but the *top* layer value shadows what's below).

**Second**, how it all is related to your code. These **factory** and **defaultFactory** functions are used in some **CSS**-related class to form an **Object** representation of the style: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/styles/CSSStyleDeclaration.html

So, you can use that **prototype** hack to form a generic **Object** with a *chain* of layers upon layers of **CSS** declarations... probably. You saw that **JSON** doesn't perceive anything but the *top* layer, I have no idea if **CSS** classes act differently or not.

I think, working with **CSS** should be less hack-y and more straightforward.

Good luck figuring it out.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to build a chain of defaultFactory using HAXE. I know Javascript is very easy because Javascript support prototype and new Function. I add another two defaultFactory functions, and let you know the code meaning. Could you use HAXE to construct a chain of defaultFactory?

Comment: As I already told you above, you should stop trying to carbon copy it to **HAXE**. The script you have builds (it is visible now) a **CSS** description object, not in one go but by merging multiple objects (namely, the chain of them), some of them have the same properties (see **paddingTop**) that mask the relevant properties in earlier objects. So, there are 2 things to do: 1) Figure, how to apply **CSS** without **CSSStyleDeclaration** class and 2) Build the **CSS** object other way than this **prototype** madness.